# Chrome (`Version 46.0.2490.80 m`) developer tools and 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Sorry for the really bad 'title'...

I have a simple script running in Chrome (`Version 46.0.2490.80 m`) developer tools. Where is this `undefined` coming from?

[image]

This same script when run 'normally' works as expected:
[image]

Comment: click on `snippets:///1_21:11`

Comment: What do you mean by "This same script when run 'normally' works as expected: "?

Comment: The `undefined` is the *return value* of `.forEach`.

Comment: @rajuGT When I load the script as part html page, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the developer tools parses the string you provide into the console and execute it as a function **and return/print the return value**  whatever the statement you had put is returning.

Execute the below code, there is no return statement, hence it will print `undefined`.

```
(function(){
    [1,2,3].forEach(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
     });
    //no return statement //Hence undefined
})();
```

But look at the below case, the function is returning some value.

```
(function(){
    [1,2,3].forEach(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
     });
    return "YOU DONT SEE UNDEFINED NOW"; //prints the string
})();
```

whereas if it is executed by the browser script, the developer-tools prints whatever the function prints and the function returns value to its caller. (Here, developer-tools need not to print all the function return values run by browser script, then your logs becomes messed up. You will see random return values returned by each and every function.